# OnRowCommand not firing on GridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview which contains a button on each row which I'd like to fire an event. In clicking the button the event doesn't fire and all that happens is the onLoad event fires and the page reloads without the gridview being populated.

The .aspx code is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvUsers" 
        OnRowCommand="gvUsers_RowCommand"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("FirstName")%> <%# Eval("LastName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:Button ID="lnkSubmit" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Action" CommandArgument='<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>' ></asp:Button> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My aspx.cs is as follows:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = db.GetUsers("dlw@fixtureslive.com")
        Dim users As New List(Of FLLib.FixturesLive.Core.User)
        While dr.Read
            Dim u As New FLLib.FixturesLive.Core.User
            u.UserID = dr("UserID")
            u.FirstName = dr("FirstName")
            u.LastName = dr("LastNAme")
            u.Sex = dr("Sex")
            u.EmailAddress = dr("Email")
            users.Add(u)
        End While

        gvUsers.DataSource = users.ToArray
        gvUsers.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub


Sub gvUsers_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

    If e.CommandName.Equals("Submit") Then
        Dim oItem As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim RowIndex As Integer = oItem.RowIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted the `Handles gvUsers.RowCommand` part. Change your event signature like this

```
Sub gvUsers_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvUsers.RowCommand
```